# Proving subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to prove that for all $r,s\in\mathbb{R}$
\begin{pmatrix}
r-s\\
r+2s\\
-s\\
\end{pmatrix}
is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.
I started with:

**1. Contains origin)** It contains the origin when $r=s=0$

**2. Closed under addition)** $$\begin{pmatrix}
r-s\\
r+2s\\
-s\\
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
r-s\\
r+2s\\
-s\\
\end{pmatrix}=2\begin{pmatrix}
r-s\\
r+2s\\
-s\\
\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R^3}\text{ (I'm not sure about this step)}$$

**3. Closed under multiplication)**$$c\begin{pmatrix}
r-s\\
r+2s\\
-s\\
\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R^3}\text{ (also unsure about what should be stated here?)}$$
What else can I add or change to 2. and 3. that would make this a proof?

Comment: You can break this into $r\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}+s\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 2 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}$ and show that that spans a subspace.

Comment: @JohnDouma Thank you

Comment: Closed under addition means that the sum of any two elements in the set is again in the set, not that adding one element of the set with itself gives an element of the set. Not only are you checking the wrong sum, you did not check that the sum was in the set in question (the issue is not whether it is in $\mathbb{R}^3$).

Comment: Also, what tou wrote is wrong. You don't want to prove that for any choice of $r$ and $s$ that one vector forms a subspace, which is what you wrote. You want to prove that the set that contains *all* vectors you get by taking all possible choices of $r$ and $s$, *that* set, is a subspace.

Comment: Condition 1. is unnecessary since by Condition 3. you can get the zero vector by taking $c=0$ if the subspace is not empty and I think this is not allowed.

Comment: @BobDobbs what's not allowed?

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins emptiness

Comment: @BobDobbs so prove it's closed under scalar multiplication and then let $c=0$ to prove it's not empty? I can't say $r=s=0$?

Comment: @BobDobbs: You are incorrect that you can prove nonemptiness from closure under scalar multiplication. The empty set is closed under sums and under scalar multiplication... but is empty. Condition 1 may be replaced by simply proving your set is nonempty, but nonemptiness cannot be derived from condition 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2, you have to show that 2 elements of the given form when added gets you another element of the given form.  In other words, you can't use the same $r,s$ for each.   so let $r,s,x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, you need to show that
$$\begin{pmatrix}
r-s\\
r+2s\\
-s\\
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
x-y\\
x+2y\\
-y\\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
r-s+x-y\\
r+2s+x+2y\\
-s-y\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
is of that form,  i.e. you can find real numbers $a,b$ such that $$r-s+x-y=a-b$$
$$r+2s+x+2y=a+2b$$
$$-s-y=-b$$

Obviously $a$ and $b$ will be in terms of $r,s,x,y$,  it should be pretty obvious what the values have to be.

Similar for #3

Comment: I guess I'm still not seeing what's missing for #3. Do I simply multiply $c$ through the vector and then let $cr=z$ and $cs=w$ to show the result is still of the same form as the original?

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. I solved your question in a different way.

...

As I said in the comments, the first condition is not necessary and the second and the third conditions can be combined to make only one condition. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace

**SUB-SPACE CONDITION:** A nonempty subset $W$ is a subspace of the vector space $V$ over the field $K$, if, whenever $w_1$, $w_2$ are elements of $W$ and $c_1$, $c_2$ are elements of $K$, it follows that $c_1 w_1 + c_2 w_2$ is in $W$.

Note that:

i) Sub-space condition $\implies$ 1. Condition: Let $c_1=c_2=0\in K$, $w_1=w_2=w\in W$. There is such an element $w$ since $W\neq\emptyset.$

ii) Sub-space condition $\implies$ 2. Condition: Let $c_1=c_2=1\in K$, $w_1,w_2\in W$ any.

iii) Sub-space condition $\implies$ 3. Condition: Let $c_1\in K$ any, $c_2=0\in K$, $w_1=w\in K$ any, $w_2=0\in W$.

Now, let me solve your question in this way by checking only one condition:

Let $w_1=(r_1-s_1,r_1+2s_1,-s_1)$ and  $w_2=(r_2-s_2,r_2+2s_2,-s_2)$ be two vectors in the sub-space $W$ you wrote. And let $c_1,c_2\in K=\Bbb{R}$. Then, here is kinda mind confusing, but we can show that $c_1w_1+c_2w_2=(r-s,r+2s,-s)$ where $r=c_1r_1+c_2r_2$ and $s=c_1s_1+c_2s_2$. So, Sub-space condition is satisfied and $W$ is a sub-space.

I think they separate this condition into three sub-conditions  to give quick answers to sub-space questions. Let me give an example: Let $A=\{(s,s+1)|s\in\Bbb{R}\}$. By your condition 1, for some $s$, we must have $(s,s+1)=(0,0)$. Then we have $s=s+1=0$ but then $s=s+1$ gives $0=1$. Contradiction. $A$ is not a sub-space.