# Find All Vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

> Let $A$ be a $2\times2$ matrix and $m$ be any non-zero real number. Find all vector spaces.
>
> $S_1=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}; y=mx \right\}$
>
> $S_2=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}; |x|+|y|=0 \right\}$

Hi,
I’m studying about linear algebra
and I can’t understand well about vector spaces.
How to solve this prob?

Comment: Look up the [vector space axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition_and_basic_properties), then work out which sets match them.

Comment: Welcome. You should know that you have to check the axioms, and you should also have some intuition about what is ‘linear’ and what is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check this post and my answer there for sub-space condition and its sub conditions: [Proving subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4545510/proving-subspaces/4546409#4546409)

S1. YES. It is a sub-space. Since $c_1(x_1,mx_1)+c_2(x_2,mx_2)=(x,mx)$ where $x=c_1x_1+c_2x_2$.

S2. NO. It is not a sub-space. For example, $(1,m)+(2,4m)=(3,5m)\neq (3,9m)$.

S3. YES. It is a sub-space. Because, $S_3=\{(0,0)\}$ is the trivial sub-space.

S4. NO. It is not a sub-space. This is the solution set of a non-homogenous equation. "Subspaces are solutions of homogenous equations." Or you can also show that from the sub-space condition. Writing in vector matrix notation by MatJax takes some time.

S5. YES. It is a sub-space. It is the solution set of the homogenous equation
$$(A-mI)=\left[\begin{array} & 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right].$$
Or you can also show that from the sub-space condition.